# there is no error in my python code. but i dont get any answers

Tags: python-3.x

my code is

```
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Parol Suresh\\Desktop\AAA\\girl.png")

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img_contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

img_contours = sorted(img_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

for i in img_contours:

    if cv2.contourArea(i) > 100:
        break
        mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)

        cv2.drawContours(mask, [i], -1, 255, -1)

        new_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow("Original Image", img)

        cv2.imshow("Image with background removed", new_img)

        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Did you really put a `break` inside the `if` block? The rest of the code will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using a `break` immediately after the `if` statement.

This will end the `for` loop **and** any subsequent code contained inside the `for` loop, including anything inside the `if` statement.

For example:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     if True:
...         break
...         print(“Hello”)
...     print(i)
... 
>>> 
# nothing ever prints
```

Get rid of the `break` statement and it should work.

As an aside - 99% of the time you do not want a `break` statement. 99% of anything you want to do can be solved by using other code.

If you **absolutely have to** use a `break`, then it should be that 1% time where it’s directly required and there’s no other choice.